# How to use UnitVectorLayer in a NetChain?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

How can I create a `NetChain` with `UnitVectorLayer` inside?
In this way I receive this error:

```
NetChain[{LinearLayer[1, "Input" -> 5], UnitVectorLayer[8, "Input" -> 1]}]
```

> NetChain::ninctyp2: Incompatible types for output of layer 1, LinearLayer[{1},...], and input to layer 2, UnitVectorLayer[8,...]; a length-1 vector is not compatible with a length-1 vector of integers between 1 and 8, respectively.

Or

```
NetChain [{LinearLayer[1, "Input" -> 5], ThreadingLayer[LogisticSigmoid[#] + 1 &], ThreadingLayer[Round[#] &], UnitVectorLayer[2, "Input" -> 1]}]
```

> NetChain::tyfail2: Inferred inconsistent shapes for output of third layer (a length-1 vector of integers between 1 and 2 versus a vector).

Or

```
NetChain [{LinearLayer[1, "Input" -> 5], ThreadingLayer[LogisticSigmoid[#] + 1 &], ThreadingLayer[IntegerPart[#] &], UnitVectorLayer[2, "Input" -> 1]}]
```

> ThreadingLayer::invscf: IntegerPart[#1]& could not be symbolically evaluated as a binary scalar function.

Comment: UnitVectorLayer works on a integers which LinearLayer returns reals. This seems like the crux of the issue...

Comment: Solutions as `NetChain [{LinearLayer[1, "Input" -> 5], 
  ThreadingLayer[LogisticSigmoid[#] + 1 &], ThreadingLayer[Chop[#] &],
   UnitVectorLayer[2, "Input" -> 1]}]` give errors like: `NetChain::tyfail2: Inferred inconsistent shapes for output of third layer (a length-1 vector of integers between 1 and 2 versus a vector).`